# Djongo search error string with parentheses

Tags: django, mongodb, orm, parentheses, djongo

I'm working on a website using Django template and MongoDB.

I implemented a search but some items have parentheses in their fields. When I use contains or icontains function to search in the database, it throw me an error or doesnt find the item.

For example, if I search

> "Test (test"

it will throw a regular expression missing error.

If I search

> "Test (test)"

It won't find anything

I manage to find that parentheses are not considered as string for mongo. I tried to escape parentheses with \ ( and \\ ) but it doesn't work.

I don't know what I can do.

Comment: You should use backslash for escape-ing instead of forward-slash

Comment: Yes I wrote the wrong character in my post, I edited it so there no more this mistake. I was using backslash

Answer (score 0):

@Lop Castro, I would suggest you use regex in your case. You can check the documentation of Django how to use regex with ORM.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#regex

Comment: Well I know nothing about regex so I will try but it will take a moment thanks